# Gracefully shutdown a spring integration flow

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration application, which I want to shutdown gracefully. 
The application runs within a docker container and the flow I want to shutdown transfers a decent amount of XML Files from one external system to another.

The requirements are: If the application has to shutdown, the current file transfer should complete and no further files should be touched after.

What I've learned and done so far:
  - docker stop sends a SIGTERM to the containers main process followed by a SIGKILL after 10 seconds (configurable with the --time=x option)
  - I implemented an ApplicationListener and registered it as @Bean, so it will be registered at the applications context.
  - the Flow uses a poller with a transactionManager, so the ApplicationListener can determine if the poller has an open transaction and if so, the Listener waits an amount of time.

My problem is now:
With this solution I can wait until the current file transfer is finished, but I cannot tell the flow to stop reading inbound files. If the transfer completed and another file arrived while the ApplicationListener was waiting, the Flow will grab the file and start another transfer, which probably will abandon while the SIGKILL arrives.
The injection of the flow as Lifecycle and the call to stop() don't seem to work as I thought.

My question is, is there a way to tell the Flow, that he should finish his work but should not listen on any arriving messages?

Here's my code so far:
OutboundFlow:

```
  @Bean
  public PseudoTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new PseudoTransactionManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
    final ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor processor = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    processor.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(processor);
  }


  @Bean
  public PollerSpec orderOutboundFlowTempFileInPoller() {
    return Pollers
        .fixedDelay(pollerDelay)
        .maxMessagesPerPoll(100)
        .transactional(transactionManager())
        .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow orderOutboundFlowTempFileIn() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(temporaryPath + '/' + OrderUtils.SUBDIR_TMP_ORDER))
                .filterFunction(
                    f -> OrderUtils.fileInputFilter(f, partnerConfigRepo, "orderOutboundFlowTempFileIn")),
            e -> e.poller(orderOutboundFlowTempFileInPoller())) ...
```

Application:

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public GracefulShutdown gracefulShutdown() {
    return new GracefulShutdown();
  }

  private static class GracefulShutdown implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GracefulShutdown.class);

    @Autowired
    private Lifecycle orderOutboundFlowTempFileIn;

    @Override public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
      LOG.info("Trying to gracefully shutdown App");
      ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
      PollerSpec outboundFlowTempFileInPoller = context.getBean(PollerSpec.class, "orderOutboundFlowTempFileInPoller");

      orderOutboundFlowTempFileIn.stop();
      TransactionInterceptor transactionManager = (TransactionInterceptor) (outboundFlowTempFileInPoller.get()
          .getAdviceChain()
          .iterator().next());
      if (transactionManager.getTransactionManager() instanceof AbstractPlatformTransactionManager) {
        final TransactionStatus transaction = transactionManager.getTransactionManager().getTransaction(null);
        LOG.info("This is the transaction: " + transaction.toString() + ", isActive? " + !transaction.isCompleted());
        while (!transaction.isCompleted()) {
          try {
            LOG.info("Still active, waiting 30 more seconds");
            Thread.sleep(30000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          }
        }
        LOG.info("Transaction completed");
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually have just to stop a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` for the `Files.inboundAdapter()`. For that purpose you need to add an `.id()` to the `e` lambda.
And use that id to retrieve a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` when you need to stop it.

This way you stop to receive new files immediately and those on-the-fly are going to be finished properly.

There is no reason to stop the whole flow from here, since all downstream components are passive.

Comment: This works to prevent the inbound adapter from reading files, but the outbound file transfer to the remote host is killed instantly, so there will be unfinished an therefore corrupted files. In this case the send()-method from the RemoteFileTemplate threw a MessagingExcpetion caused by an InterruptedIOException. Is there a way to achieve both? Finishing the current file and prevent new incoming messages?
The messages can be large and take a while to upload to the remote host.